# How can I insert foreign key id of a related object with Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, dapper

I have the following classes:

```
public class Template
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool SignaturePerLine { get; set; }
        public string SpecialTest { get; set; }
        public TemplateType TemplateType { get; set; } = new TemplateType();
        public int StandardTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    }

public class TemplateType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool Pictures { get; set; }
        public bool Video { get; set; }
        public bool Matrix { get; set; }    
    }
```

My database tables are predominantly the same except my `Template` table has a foreign key of `TemplateTypeId` which stores the `Id` from the `TemplateType` table. Pretty standard stuff.

I am using Dappper to try to insert a fully populated `Template` object like so...

```
string sql = $@"insert into dbo.Template (Title, SignaturePerLine, StandardTime, StartDate, SpecialTest) 
                     values (@Title, @SignaturePerLine, @StandardTime, @StartDate, @SpecialTest);";
        
connection.Execute(sql,Template);
```

**The issue...**

My problem occurs when I try to add in the `TemplateTypeId`.
How can I tell Dapper to insert this?

I had hoped I could do something like this:

```
string sql = $@"insert into dbo.Template (Title, SignaturePerLine, StandardTime, StartDate, SpecialTest, TemplateTypeId) 
      values (@Title, @SignaturePerLine, @StandardTime, @StartDate, @SpecialTest, @TemplateType.Id);";
```

But that does not work.

I could maybe add each property as a set of `DynamicParameters` but I was hoping to avoid that approach as some of my other classes have 20+ properties.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: just add `TemplateTypeId` property to `Template` class

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping to avoid having to do that because it means duplicating properties in my classes whenever there is a foreign key relationship.

Comment: Or you could separate the models, have one to read (the current template class) and another to insert, that would have the property TemplateTypeId and not the TemplateType.

And you can always to use a abstract "base model" that will have the common properties so you don't need to duplicate the properties

Answer (score 2):

Usually what I do in these situations is create two sets of models. 'DataAccess' models, which are 1 to 1 with the database and 'Domain' models for end user. Furthermore create mappings from domain to dataAccess and vice-versa.

As you mentioned, having models with more 20 properties, this helps you manage the data more easly.

```
namespace DataAccess.Models;

public class TemplateDb
{
    public TemplateDb(int id, string title, bool signaturePerLine, string specialTest, int templateTypeId, int standardTime, DateTime startDate)
    {
        Id = id;
        Title = title ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(title));
        SignaturePerLine = signaturePerLine;
        SpecialTest = specialTest ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(specialTest));
        TemplateTypeId = templateTypeId;
        StandardTime = standardTime;
        StartDate = startDate;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool SignaturePerLine { get; set; }
    public string SpecialTest { get; set; }
    public int TemplateTypeId { get; set; }
    public int StandardTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateTypeDb
{
    public TemplateTypeDb(int id, string name, string description, bool pictures, bool video, bool matrix)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        Description = description ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(description));
        Pictures = pictures;
        Video = video;
        Matrix = matrix;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Pictures { get; set; }
    public bool Video { get; set; }
    public bool Matrix { get; set; }
}

namespace Domain.Models;

public class Template
{
    public Template(int id, string title, bool signaturePerLine, string specialTest, TemplateType templateType, int standardTime, DateTime startDate)
    {
        Id = id;
        Title = title ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(title));
        SignaturePerLine = signaturePerLine;
        SpecialTest = specialTest ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(specialTest));
        TemplateType = templateType ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(templateType));
        StandardTime = standardTime;
        StartDate = startDate;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool SignaturePerLine { get; set; }
    public string SpecialTest { get; set; }
    public TemplateType TemplateType { get; set; }
    public int StandardTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateType
{
    public TemplateType(int id, string name, string description, bool pictures, bool video, bool matrix)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Pictures = pictures;
        Video = video;
        Matrix = matrix;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Pictures { get; set; }
    public bool Video { get; set; }
    public bool Matrix { get; set; }
}

public class Mapper
{
    public TemplateDb ToDb(Template template)
    {
        return new TemplateDb(
            id: template.Id,
            title: template.Title,
            signaturePerLine: template.SignaturePerLine,
            specialTest: template.SpecialTest,
            templateTypeId: template.TemplateType.Id,
            standardTime: template.StandardTime,
            startDate: template.StartDate
            );
    }

    public Template ToDomain(TemplateDb templateDb, TemplateTypeDb templateTypeDb)
    {
        return new Template(
            id: templateDb.Id,
            title: templateDb.Title,
            signaturePerLine: templateDb.SignaturePerLine,
            specialTest: templateDb.SpecialTest,
            templateType: new TemplateType(
                id: templateTypeDb.Id,
                name: templateTypeDb.Name,
                description: templateTypeDb.Description,
                pictures: templateTypeDb.Pictures,
                video: templateTypeDb.Video,
                matrix: templateTypeDb.Matrix
            ),
            standardTime: templateDb.StandardTime,
            startDate: templateDb.StartDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Radu you solution looks good. I was already beginning to wonder whether some form of DTO was the way to go. However, it still seems like a lot of additional work for what is surely a fairly common scenario, that I had hoped could be catered for by Dapper.

Comment: @Radu Thanks for your answer... it explains how to handle a "one-to-many" relationship... are you able to expand on this to show how you would handle a "many-to-many" relationship (even though I know it's out of the scope of the original question...)?